# Was Bayonetta PS3 performance optimized?

Tags: ps3, bayonetta

In [Bayonetta](http://www.ign.com/articles/2009/12/22/bayonetta-review) review for PS3 there is specific accent on poor performance of the PS3 version. I wonder if for the passed time, any patches were out that addressed this issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, patches did improve performance on the PS3: http://kotaku.com/5458852/bayonetta-updated-for-ps3-load-times-improved

Answer (score 0):

The ps3 version of bayonetta is perfectly playable. There are no obviously long loading times.
Even in the remaining loading times you can practice your combat.
I suggest to install the game on hard drive.

This is still one of my favourite games.